# Sitecore - some items are missing in index after performing full index rebuild

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

We are facing an issue in our sitecore instance. When we perform full index rebuild in sitecore, we have noticed that some of the items are missing and they are not found throughout solr index. We have checked log files as well but no error traces are found. Then we tried publishing in web database i.e. Going to desptop --> Selecting web database from below --> publishing parent folders of the missing items and those items are available in the index again. Any suggestion or help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Lalit S. Joshi

Answer (score 0):

There might be couples of reasons for failure some items while indexing. Please check the below points:

Check the crawling.log files and see any object reference error is thrown after complete the full index rebuilding.

Sometimes Event Queue table keeps growing in size and eventually getting flooded, so clear this one.

If you want to index every template, then do not include anything in the exclude Template section. If this is added, then those items will not be indexed. Even also check the field types of your template those needs to be indexed.

Check the security of the items or some conditions are there for that result, those items are might not be getting published properly.

Did you write any custom logic for e.g. computed fields for Solr index, check the log if they are throwing any error.

You didn't mention any specific error, so I have tried to mention some suggestion above. Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have checked for error in SOLR as well as Sitecore log file. There are no error during or after indexing. I haven't checked the first and the second option you've mentioned. I will check them and let you know soon.Thanks

Comment: Hi, 

I have checked all the sitecore log files and haven't found any error. I have checked elmah as well. I have put try catch in computed index and no errors are found there. I have checked crawling.log file as per your suggestion and I have found entries of those missing records there. Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: Pl check that log files are update properly or not . As you mentioned entries of those missing records , which entries are you talking about .

Comment: I have checked all the possible sitecore log files properly. All the log files are update properly. By missing records I mean those records which are "missing in solr index" after I "Rebuild Index" in Sitecore but they are found back in SOLR when I publish the parent folder of missing items in this manner "Going to desptop --> Selecting web database from below --> publishing parent folders".I am talking about this kind of log in Crawling.log file "20216 13:48:16 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] ItemAdded sitecore_web_index|sitecore://web/{A4A54FE1-8752-4D6A-BF06-B0BEA71E4337}?lang=en&ver=1"